# Can someone place a request for joining a developer team on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I was wondering if it is possible to place a request for joining a developer team either on Stack Overflow or Careers. If so, how would one go about that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure - it is possible.

Go to the careers ad for the job and apply:

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/28723/web-developer-stack-exchange-stack-exchange?a=xW2dFGU&searchTerm=stack%20exchange

Comment: No salary mentioned? Hmmm wonder what it is.

Comment: Thank you for a quick response I will check it out.

Comment: @mattytommo - Consider that the HQ is in New York.

Comment: Yes I was just referring to remote developing. Currently I am doing that with a couple of companies one in Australia and another one in west coast us while I reside in east coast us. I was just wondering if I can expand a bit without overloading myself.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - Stack Exchange will be looking for full time employment, no part timers, sorry.

Comment: I understand. Just a thought. I still am a bit away from giving up my day job. I can't complain about the income though, it's been really good but I haven't written an angry bird yet. Thanks for being supportive and kind.

Comment: @CodeMonkey - Not sure what you mean by giving up the day job. If you apply and get the job at Stack Exchange, it would be the day job - you would be an employee of the company, not a free lancer.

Comment: Oh had no clue. Currently I develop part time and I am senior manager at a restaurant group in east coast. But iOS developing has been kind to me and I like to go full time soon. I though getting to work with other developers would add on to what I got. I can still peruse being a developer on the side but at least ill be around codes all day. That's what I was looking for. I'm going to look into the stack exchange and see what happens. Thanks again